# Creating a JS widget using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have one rails application App1 in which there is an Event section.But now I want that there should be a separate Rails App App2 for the Event.And a JS code, that will be used the App1 to fetch all the Event Lists,Event Creation etc.from the App2.

Yours suggestions are welcomed.

Please suggest me the approach for this.

Thanks,
gsoni

Answer (score 2):

If you have used scaffolding for the `Event` model in `App1` then you can simply visit:

`http://app1/events.json`

and use:

```
$.getJSON('http://app1/events.json',function(data){
  $.each(data,function(k,v){
    /* Do something with each event */
  });
});
```

If you have not used scaffolding for the `Event` model in `App` then you simply need to create an action like so

```
def some_action
  @events = Event.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: @books }
  end
end
```

and use `http://app1/controller_name/some_action.json` in the above example.

The same principle works for creation, edits, etc. Just scaffold a model and use the default code to get an idea of how it works, and change accordingly.